# Win RT Windows Phone 8.1: Capture Element Hangs when hold back button

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera, windows-runtime, image-capture

I have a CaptureElement in my WP8.1 App, My CaptureElement Stuck on one frame if I do below steps:

1. Open that page which have capture element, it shows my camera preview.
2. Press and hold hardware back button of phone. Recent apps will be shown on screen.
3. Don't tap on any app just again press hardware back button one time.
4. It will take me back to capture element screen but now the preview is showing last frame when I press and hold back button.

I have tried this on default camera app of phone and it works ok but flicks a little bit, seems that they have handled it.

How can I handle it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

By surfing on internet I came to know that this suspends the application so I have to handle suspension states.
Just adding these simple lines, it worked perfectly :)

```
public MediaCapture()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    Application.Current.Resuming += App_resuming;
    Application.Current.Suspending += App_Suspending;
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

async void App_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    if (captureManager != null)
    {
        await captureManager.StopPreviewAsync();
        captureManager.Dispose();
        captureManager = null;
    }
}

private void App_resuming(object sender, object e)
{
    if (Frame.Content == this)
    {
        InitializeCamera();
    }
}
```